# Core Data Relationships fetch

Tags: iphone, ios4, core-data, entity-relationship

Ok, I thought I had this but I am not getting the results that I am expecting. Hopefully someone can help.

I have two entities Person and Timesheet with one attribute to-many relationship:
Person.timesheet<--->>Timesheet.user. 
The code below works but when I try to add a second timesheet entry it seems to override the first?

I have looked at the Apple Docs and they are a little vague on this subject.

```
//Add

NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
Person *personAdded = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
Timesheet *timesheet = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Timesheet" inManagedObjectContext:context];;
timesheet.time = @"10:00 Friday";
timesheet.timestamp = [NSDate date];

NSSet *timesheetSet = [NSSet setWithObject:timesheet];

personAdded.name = @"Darren";
personAdded.job = @"Job to be Done";
personAdded.timesheet = timesheetSet;

NSError *error = nil;
[context save:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"[ERROR] COREDATA: Save raised an error - '%@'", [error description]);
}

NSLog(@"[SUCCESS] COREDATA: Inserted new User to database!");

// Load

NSEntityDescription *personEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity: personEntity];

error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (!results || error) {
    NSLog(@"[ERROR] COREDATA: Fetch request raised an error - '%@'", [error description]);
    [request release];
}
NSLog(@"Results: %@",results);

Person *firstUser = [results objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"First User's name: %@",firstUser.name);
NSLog(@"First User's time %@",[[firstUser.timesheet anyObject] valueForKeyPath:@"timestamp"]);
```

I am wondering if it could be because I am actually setting the Person.timesheet key with the NSSet and not the actual Table? OR could it be that I am not calling the results correctly?

Thanks,
Darren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a generated "CoreDataGeneratedAccessors" method in your Person.h file which gives you a method

```
[personAdded addTimesheet:timesheetSet];
```

which creates the links for you ?

Core Data normally generates an add and a remove method for any relationships you define.

Post your person.h file if this is not clear.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. I have thought that these methods might be the answer but I have never been able to get them to work. After reading your response, I had another look at it and realised that I have to add the methods to the header file. Once I did that I was able call it which worked but when I call it I get a warning stating that 'NSSet' may not respond to 'addTimesheet:'. I have looked at the rest of the code and it all seems to look fine? Any Ideas

Comment: Its all good now the error was my fault trying to run the method on personAdded.timesheet and not just person added. Thanks so much for the solution, I am glad it was something as simple as that.